# UDF for formatting numbers into strings in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

In Pig, I want to get a numeric column out let's say "12345" and cast it to a string with formatting like "$12,345".

Are there existing UDF's to help with standard formatting like adding dollar signs, commas, percents, etc? I haven't seen any in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my python UDF that you can leverage.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("formatted:chararray")
def toDol(number):
    s = '%d' % number
    groups = []
    while s and s[-1].isdigit():
        groups.append(s[-3:])
        s = s[:-3]
        res = s + ','.join(reversed(groups))
        res = '$' + res
    return res
```

This is how your pig script is going to look like

```
Register 'locale_udf.py' using jython as myfuncs;
DT = LOAD 'sample_data.txt' Using PigStorage() as (dol:float);
DTR = FOREACH DT GENERATE dol,myfuncs.toDol(dol) as formattedstring;
dump DTR;
```

This should work for you.